# I dont know why result of that code is NONE

Tags: python

I dont know why result of that code is NONE:

```
s = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
b=s.remove(1)
print(b)
```

And now, its ok.

```
s = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
s.remove(1)
print(s)
```

Tell me why so different.

Comment: Because `remove` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The remove() method only removes the given element from the list.

It doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

The `remove()` does not return any value means `b` is getting `None`.Instead of `remove()` you can use `pop()` to get the return value as given below:-

```
s = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
b=s.pop(1)   # Here `remove()` returns `None`, hence the value of `b` is `None`. 
print(b)

s = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
s.remove(1)
print(s)
```

I hope it may help you.